# No root user password for MariaDB

Tags: password, mariadb

I've gone through the process of installing MariaDB several times now, and it has never asked me to create a root password.  The upshot of this is I can't get in and create the database.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find what!

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL 5.7.6 and newer as well as MariaDB 10.1.20 and newer, use the following command.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

For MySQL 5.7.5 and older as well as MariaDB 10.1.20 and older, use:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can connect by root from localhost from root shell without password.
If you don't known root password, there is a way to start mysql without using mysql db, where users and passwords stored. Run each command with sudo, except  mysql console commands:

```
# service mysql stop
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

# mysql -u root
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') where User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;

# service mysql restart
```

Now you can login with new password: `# mysql -u root -p`

Update: Its better not change password for root, but create new user with all privileges who can connect only from localhost. When in mysql console do following:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

If you need external connections to mysql - limit it by hosts and/or don`t grant all privileges and limit to only required databases(the * in above example).

Comment: No, I couldn't.  I tried it, and all I got was "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: I updated answer, with a way to login without passwords at all, so able to reset any password

Comment: Another error message:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Comment: Are you run above commands by root terminal or sudo?

Comment: Yes.  I made sure to run them with sudo.

Comment: Okay, I rebooted and retried the above.  This time it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @LeonidMew It is great that you can use search engine an keyboard for copying and pasting commands. But are you sure that `“NEWPASSWORD”` and `’root’` will be normally interpreted by terminal????

Comment: @N0rbert Either I use copy&paste from search results or not, I known what I'm writing about.

Comment: @LeonidMew Anyway consider to edit your post to remove wrong quotes.